# Detect within link directive whenever input blurred

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an input with a link directive. My question is: is it possible to detect within the link function in the directive when the input loses focus?

Here is my directive:

```
appDrct.directive('formattedDate', ['$filter', 'formatter', function ($filter, formatter) {
    return {
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
            ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function (viewValue) {
                var val = element.val();
                if(!val)
                    return viewValue;
                var dateStr = $filter('date')(val,'dd.MM.yyyy');
                if(dateStr == undefined)
                    return viewValue;
                var parsed = viewValue;

                if(**BLURRED**){
                   do something....
                }
                try
                {
                    var dateParts = dateStr.split('.');
                    parsed = new Date(dateParts[2],dateParts[1]-1,dateParts[0]);
                }
                catch(e){
                }
                return parsed;
            });
        },
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel'
    };
}]);
```

JADE:

```
input.form-control(formatted-date='mybirth', name='birth' ,placeholder='jj.mm.aaaa', type="text", datepicker-popup="dd.MM.yyyy", ng-model="mybirth", is-open="$parent.opened[0]", close-text="Close")
```

Plunker of an example:

http://plnkr.co/edit/t9ERna33YcG8ubDqDPgy?p=preview

Comment: Here it is... let me know if you need something else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may also use `element.on('blur', yourFn)` in the `link` function

Comment: I tried that but the function is called each time I type something in the input and not only when it loses focus...

Comment: I just added the line `element.on('blur', function () {console.log(1);});` in the `link` function in your plunkr and it worked fine for me. Perhaps there is something missing in your example that messes with the `blur` event in your project?

Comment: Oh I see that I need to wrap it into a function...why is that?

Comment: the `element.on()` method expects a function that it will invoke whenever the event occurs on the element. Moreover, you have put that line inside the new parser for the `ctrl`. So the function will be bound to `blur` more than once. Instead, you have to bind it outside of `ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function (viewValue) {...})`

Comment: I modified your plunkr accordingly: http://plnkr.co/edit/wlggq4VqmLZ9MDhzYa3Z?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

You can use ng-blur directive please see here http://plnkr.co/edit/Umx2czSRtgh3Cb2rKXYf?p=preview

```
  <p class="input-group">
    <input id="birth" formattedDate="mybirth" placeholder="dd.mm.yyyy" type="text" datepicker-popup="dd.MM.yyyy" 
    ng-model="mybirth" is-open="opened" 
    ng-blur="action()"
    close-text="Close" class="form-control"/><span class="input-group-btn">
      <button type="button" ng-click="open($event)" class="btn btn-default"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button></span>
  </p>
```